# Why do I get type errors when resolving this Promise inside a generic method?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add some types to this WebSocket protocol:

```
type Action =
    | {
        action: "change-or-create-state";
        response: string;
    }
    | {
        action: "get-state";
        response: string | null;
    };

/**
 * map an action to its response
 */
type ActionResponse<T extends Action["action"]> = Extract<
    Action,
    { action: T }
>["response"];

export async function doAction<
    TAction extends Action["action"]
>(action: TAction): Promise<ActionResponse<TAction>> { /* ... */ }
```

I'm having trouble with the types with actually *resolving* that promise, though:

```
// in reality received over websocket
const someDataFromAPI: string = '"hello world"'

export async function doAction<
    TAction extends Action["action"]
>(action: TAction): Promise<ActionResponse<TAction>> {
    return new Promise<ActionResponse<TAction>>((resolve) => {
        // I know I could just keep this as 'any' -- the real code does validation
        // which narrows the type.
        const jsonWithSpecificType: ActionResponse<TAction> = JSON.parse(someDataFromAPI);

        /** ⚠️
        Argument of type 'ActionResponse<TAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionResponse<TAction> | PromiseLike<ActionResponse<TAction>>'.
        Type 'Extract<{ action: "get-state"; response: string | null; }, { action: TAction; }>["response"]' is not assignable to type 'ActionResponse<TAction> | PromiseLike<ActionResponse<TAction>>'.
        Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'ActionResponse<TAction> | PromiseLike<ActionResponse<TAction>>'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ActionResponse<TAction> | PromiseLike<ActionResponse<TAction>>'.(2345)
        */
        resolve(jsonWithSpecificType)
    })
}
```

[Playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgTBTAZgSwHb0gBwE4HsAuuAxrgDZQjDjwAemu2+k+AnphgIJH7K6qQBeKJBEAfSAG9hImZACG3XqgBckAEREAFnNQBzeAFoGBotnhz8hgM74L8NQG5psyGav1UV+KpvY0up1kAX2dxKRcZBR4+VTV9fAMbO0dnWTcPLx98Pz1IcVQAV1JSQJkgp3BQCGhIAFs5THl+KKVmXEhkfCtXeHc+LwoqWnpGZjZORT4AJV6M+AAeABVIWktUWG6uaNQAbTUWvjUAXQA+QUgAURpsqPnnLaUAGmcJeUmVSGWQk730-vsjhVgMBIA9prN-pArDpOixIFp4EQANbgEieJhaHT6ADy2AAwmY7ABlWyWGZ9TzeUHvclzeYabR6QzGUzmSyJUn2M4CdRyKywRApYHw-oYxk4-GEywkuy0-4AJlUYNQcsp9MxTKM2BMUusnLU3MghWKDkgwtwSMeK2weGwVlRosg8RlZIhlKVNLdXnp8Q5yUN+35gqcaJsTvg+Bd8FVXkV1O2MYWcQjfssBvOxpK4GzwrQPTkpFhPSI8GQADd4LBILgK9hIAB3eAAIysxCREYd6KhuFq8AAIhY5AAxPC1DgABQAklkcrpzgByNSaeDFdr1hikWBqefZ4YMJh8lioIiQRAFY-bOC4ZV3WSLZUra7wdabd57A6oY7gE4ACg-qnvd4AEpVHHUdkG9ZVEyWZUTjOcIZDMfACmwfh0HrSAwJ7CCFigr0FkA7Y4J-H83DICsgMEeDUhkYVJ0gJFUFwDD6JIIoqwAKwKMN23gRp8E0CD5G6ecdBYedIAMAxmGXfNSBFBAr16SAywLZBYAsJQaJEYV60ErQjTkG1mO6ASMFYdgADptJFLsONbVAAHVOk0Il2CIZAUCIRZxg9BN8Jg95DQAKSJbEADlLMwIyvB-VtewHWwRx7CdJyA00iGzCIdLASBAAKyQB4P5sjhsF0Ape1QJhcEQMZ2Egec8Ipb1CKUE4JKEpiDysKxkF0VA5CbUhzPaaLsDkXtLDraraowBrPSagjYLyTDwK8AAZZB23mRq6Ravg4Pnazss+cZ6quG5uHmV5-3UX0kjTU0-ndKFsn8ZbM1NIIrWu94AOVT6fjUJ6vGOdruk64Ser6gahraGb6p2-5AqI5asNqHCNq2xG1T21ADqO7KfLq+dfDe-IilIMGjQISHev6wbhvhub-IW5HWtR1b4Ex3D5t22C2oJiIidmzMqYhvkofp2HCCZ7HmqW8Q0YxzaeZZvmgoFn95QAZgAFgAViAmzKBssjSArH97L4ZyBLcxFPOQbzxiN4IjaCIA). What am I missing? Obviously `any` works fine here, but I'm just curious what the issue is. My guess is that its something like it can't guarantee that `TAction` is the same type inside the arrow function as it was in the outer function?

Comment: This is pretty interesting and doesn't have much to do with `Promise`.  Instead it seems that some generic type aliases are not recognized as subsets of unions; the minimal example seems to be [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/w6QbEW).  I'm looking for relevant github issues but I haven't found a definite one yet.

Comment: [ms/TS#47233](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47233) seems very similar, classified as a bug, so maybe this is just a bug?  I'll keep looking

Comment: Well, that's the closest I can find.  I could write this up as an answer, or someone could file a github issue and get a more definitive answer. How would you like to proceed?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for the actually-minimal example. If you write up as an answer I will accept. I think you should file a report with your playground as well and link back to TS#47233.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can find to a canonical answer to this question is [microsoft/TypeScript#47233](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47233), which is similar to the problem here and is classified as a bug.  That *could* mean this is a bug, but it could also just be a design limitation.  If I find the time I'll open a new issue to get an authoritative answer.

I strongly suspect that the issue here is that the types `ActionResponse<TAction>` and `ActionResponse<TAction> | PromiseLike<ActionResponse<TAction>>` are both [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), and thus the compiler cannot evaluate them fully.  Since `ActionResponse<T>` involves some type manipulation like [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)) then `ActionResponse<TAction>` and `ActionResponse<TAction> | PromiseLike<ActionResponse<TAction>>` are fairly complicated and probably left unevaluated by the compiler.  So they are somewhat "opaque".

A human being can see by inspection that the former must be assignable to the latter, by the rule "`X` is always assignable to `X | Y`" and pattern-matching `ActionResponse<T>` for `X` and `PromiseLike<ActionResponse<TAction>>` for `Y`.  But the compiler is not a human being, and if it gives up on evaluating the types before considering the union assignability rule, then you get an error.

I think a minimal example for this behavior is something like

```
type F<K extends "a" | "b"> = (
    ({ x: "a"; y: "a"; } | { x: "b"; y: "b"; }) & { x: K }
)["y"];

function foo<K extends "a" | "b">(fk: F<K>): F<K> | undefined {
    return fk; // error?!
}
```

where it should be obvious to anyone that `F<K>` is assignable to `F<K> | undefined` no matter what `F<K>` is, but the compiler is unable to see it because of the complicated union discrimination and indexing going on in the definition of `F`.  I use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) instead of [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) here, but it's the same basic operation.

For now this answer is just my best educated guess about what's happening.  If I file a bug and get a definitive answer I'll come back and edit to reflect it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAaShAHsCA7AJgZygIgEN8oAfAgI3wD4oBeKACgCgo2mBvKFALgOIDcUEHyL4hAXzJQuvSuOGiqkgJRQAZDO58kE5ioDa+EPgC6A5swBmAVwwBjYAEsA9hihWXLxMjSZc-CTk+FTUjFYA1nzwCNQq0Yi05HZYEFZOGBBYMqzsAE4QwDZ57pFCAPTlUAD8AITMepbMQA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why but this seems to fix it for now -

```
export async function doAction<
    TAction extends Action["action"],
    R = ActionResponse<TAction> // <--
>(action: TAction): Promise<R> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const jsonWithSpecificType: R = JSON.parse(someDataFromAPI)  
        resolve(jsonWithSpecificType)
    })
}
```

```
const x = doAction("change-or-create-state") // : Promise<string>
const y = doAction("get-state") // : Promise<string | null>
const z = doAction("foo") // : "foo" is not assignable to parameter of type "change-or-create-state" | "get-state"
```

Comment: Thank you for the typesafe workaround! I accepted the other answer because it went more into depth about the root causes, but this is a great addition.

Comment: Glad it helped!